# Windows 10 - Username with whitespace and PATH

Tags: path, windows-10

Upon installing Windows 10 I created my admin user as `Miha Šušteršič`. Now when I install programs that need to modify the environment variable PATH, most of them don't get added. For instance this happens with MongoDB and Git, but npm got added normally.

I think this is an issue with the whitespace in the path to the variables. I tried renaming my username to `M.Sustersic`, but the system folder Users\Miha Šušteršič\ did not get updated.

Is there a way for me to change this folder name automatically (so the rest of the app dependencies on \Users\Miha Šušteršič\AppData don't get bugged) or do I need to reinstall windows?

Is there something else I am missing here? I tried adding the dependencies on my own, but nothing worked so far.

Comment: For those guys struggling to change name in step 6 of 2nd answer, change it using cmd. This is a comment to 2nd answer but I got low reputation to comment :/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See [this KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2454362) to change the name of the User Profile directory.

After you do this, you may want to make a link just in case any of your apps keep local path configuration.

```
cd C:\Users
mklink /D "Miha Šušteršič" M.Sustersic
```

Comment: In my case I wasn't able to rename it because it was saying that "the folder or file is in use". Following [this thread](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f217/unable-to-rename-user-profile-folder-under-administrator-profile-575840.html) I finished the process of Windows Media Player in my Task Manager and then I was able to edit the name.

Comment: This fixed lots of problems

Comment: I followed the article, did not execute the above commands before the restart. after restart i got a warning, i reverted the changed, rebooted and logged back. I am unlikely to choose this route but if you do before restart you should do the additional change as mentioned above

Answer (score 44):

You can actually change the folder name. It's a bit tedious but it's worth it. Make sure you know of the edition of your Windows 10 you're using first - Professional, Enterprise or Home - before carrying out these steps, cos of step 5:

1. **Right click** on Windows Start Menu option and click **Command Prompt (Admin)**

*(If you can't find Command Prompt (Admin) when you right-click on the Start Menu or search for it, you can simply go to `C:/Users/Default/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/WinX/Group3` on your pc. There, you'll find two shortcuts both named "Command Prompt"; one is for Command Prompt, and the other is for Command Prompt (Admin).Try out both shortcuts to know which is which, and then click on the one for **Command Prompt (Admin)**)*

2. In the Command Prompt (Admin), create a new/temporary admin account by entering this command: `net user Administrator /active:yes` *(Notice the space between* `Administrator` *and* `/`*)* and close the cmd
3. Next, click on the start menu and sign out of your current admin account
   (four icons above the shut down button)
4. Sign in with the new **Administrator** account you just created
5. (Skip this step only if you use the Windows **Home Edition**) Right click on the Start Menu and click **Computer Management** and open `Local Users and Groups > Users`. Right-click on the username you wish to change and select **Rename** and close the window.
6. Open `Local Disk (C) > Users` and **right-click** and rename the corresponding folder with the name you wish, just as in Step 5, and close the window.
7. Next, search for **regedit** in the search box and click on it. Now, inside the regedit (i.e. Registry Editor), go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Windows NT > Current Version > Profile List`.

In the list of identifiers under `Profile List`, find the ProfileImagePath that corresponds to the account name you wish to change. Yours should look something like this:

`ProfileImagePath  REG_EXPAND_SZ  c:\Users\Miha Šušteršič`.

Double click on the value and rename it to what you want.

8. Still in the regedit, scroll up to the top of the window and make sure the highlight is on `Computer`, then click `Edit` in the menu options just above it; then click `Find`; then enter `C:\Users\<your old username>`. In your case, that would be:

`C:\Users\Miha Šušteršič`

And search.

9. If the search brings out any result (i.e. any folder bearing your old account user name,) click on it and rename it, and then go back to `Edit` in the menu option and this time, click `Find Next` or f3. Keep on "Finding Next" this until there are no files are left to rename, then close regedit.
10. Finally, sign out of your Administrator account and sign in with your now-renamed account, and then, go on to disable the Administrator account you just signed out from. You do this by going to Command Prompt (Admin) and this time, you enter the command:

`net user Administrator /active:no`

*(Once again, notice the space between* `Administrator` *and* `/`*)*

...and close the command.

And that's it! Long and tedious, but it works. You can check also out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_rTOA4gXJI) to have a better understanding of everything I just described.

_Note: Make sure to follow every step to the letter so you don't run into more serious problems.

If you run into any issues renaming at Step 6, simply shut down your computer and restart and try again.

Also, certain files may/will not allow for renaming. It's alright; just leave them as they are and "Find Next" until there's no more file to rename._

Comment: This worked well, although it took much longer to rename all the regedit keys and values than I was expecting as there were a lot!  The only issue I've run into afterwards (at least so far) is several missing application icons from pinned tiles in the Start menu. Unpinning and repinning/repositioning to Start was required to fix this issue.

Comment: I'm current stuck at step 6 (rename folder) because windows say i have a file opened somewhere. Any suggestion?

Comment: Just shut down your computer and turn it back on. That should/will solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, after following all the steps, I was able to change the username successfully. But if I type "whoami" on command prompt, it still returns the old username. I have restarted the computer but no change. Any suggestions?

Comment: After step 5, my account is no longer visible to the system under C:/Users/ so I can't complete step 6....this is really bad

Comment: finally no more issues because of a stupid space in username, thanks!

Comment: The general idea worked well. Unfortunately, manually renaming all of the occurrences of the old username (step 8-9) would take ages in my case. For me, creating a new user to begin with will be faster. If you really want to utilize the old profile i advise you to deinstall applications which store many paths, such as Adobe Acrobat, before doing this procedure.

Comment: For the potentially tedious manual find & rename Step 8, if you have Python, for example, installed, you'd have to do this thousands of times. Instead, with Computer clicked in Registry Editor, click File -> Export, and save your registry TWO TIMES as TWO .reg files anywhere BECAUSE ONE OF THEM IS A REGISTRY BACK UP! Then, open ONE .reg file in a text editor (I used Visual Studio Code), and use the Replace feature to replace all occurrences of the old name with the new, space-free name. Save that .reg file, then run it. This should do it, and it worked for me. Upvote please for others to see.

Comment: This did unfortunately not work for me in Windows 11. I followed the guide and changed all the registry keys I could, but after re-logging, explorer kept crashing, and all kinds of things didn't work anymore. Had to revert to an earlier recovery save.