# When I run npx react-native run-android command it gives me following error

Tags: react-native

[image]

I don't now where this path is coming from because my path is C:/Users/Aditya Upadhyay

Comment: I think you have a space in your username for the machine, here is a similar question with some useful tips to solve it https://stackoverflow.com/q/64417344/3784556

Comment: Thank you so much it solve my first problem but after that it gives me Task :app:processDebugMainManifest failed error

Comment: can you help me to solve it

Answer (score 1):

Open android folder in android studio and run from android

Check environment path

Comment: can I run react-native project in android studio?

Comment: yes. just open android folder in android studio.